# Need advice on Apache 2.2.22 Win Server 2003, memory leak

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, bandwidth, httpd.conf, memory-leak

I'm running Apache 2.2.22 on Windows Server 2003

I'm serving some tutorial videos on the webpage to some registered users. The webpage has up to 30 users at a time, I know this because of analytics.

The server hangs from time to time, memory and cpu usage seems to be ok. I think the problem is random memory leak on child process threads.

I already found some tweaks that I can use on httpd.conf:

> KeepAlive Off
>
> AcceptFilter http none
>
> AcceptFilter https none
>
> EnableSendfile off
>
> EnableMMAP off

I activated server-status, and right now I'm concerned about the total traffic. The web is consuming aroung 50GB/hour in total traffic.

Could this be a bandwith problem?

> **Apache server Status**
>
> Server uptime: 1 hour 12 minutes 23 seconds
>
> Total accesses: 6705 - Total Traffic: 68.1 GB
>
> 1.54 requests/sec - 16.1 MB/second - 10.4 MB/request
>
> 10 requests currently being processed, 54 idle workers

Comment: What is the server maximum bandwidth?

Comment: Hi, I'm confused about the bandwidth. This is a physical server, not a Cloud Server. I suppose it's maximum bandwidth comes from Internet connection. I already did a speed test and I have a speed of 5 Mbps for Download and Upload